# Very green VBA user, everything below 2nd line works, but how do I make above it work?

Tags: excel, vba, testing

I have made a test in Excel for my cousin; right now if you get the answer correct then you have to press a button for the next question, but I would like the macro to show "correct" for 2 seconds then move on to the next question without having to press a button. Please help

I've tried below, it used to be regular button click macro, but i've tried to change it and it won't run

```
Sub answer_correct()

If K11.Value == "Correct!" Then

Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 65)

Range("I11").Cells.ClearContents

ActiveSheet.Range("I11").Select

Range("F18").Value = Range("F18").Value + 1

End If

End Sub
```

I get syntax error, I expect the counter to go up by 1 and the question to reset

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you [edit] your question and post the error message as text so others may search this solution. Currently the title is too vague to help anyone find it or be of use. The goal of SE sites is to become a resource of knowledge, of answers, for years to come.

Comment: When you *get syntax error*, you also get an error message, and that error message should be included in your post. It's information you already have on your screen, but we can't see your screen from here. Adding it to you question makes it much easier for people to help you, and it's to your advantage to make it as easy as possible for them to do so by including the details you already have about the problem. Also, having the error message in the post means that it's searchable, so it can be found by others in the future who are trying to solve the same sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

VBA never uses `==` for a comparison operator. Use `=` instead. Also, I presume that you want to refer to *range* `K11` rather than some unspecified variable. Thus, replace

```
If K11.Value == "Correct!" Then
```

by

```
If Range("K11").Value = "Correct!" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Tips:

- In order to avoid confusion, used a With Statement declaring the sheet you want to target
- use "." before "Range" to impose the range in the Sheet With Statement"
- Avoid ActiveSheet & Select
- If you will refer to a range more than one times used With Statement.

  ```
  Sub answer_correct()

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

      If .Range("K11").Value = "Correct!" Then

          .Range("A1").Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 65)

          With .Range("I11")
              .ClearContents
              .Select '<- I keep .Select to show the With Statement for the range.
          End With

          .Range("F18").Value = .Range("F18").Value + 1

      End If

  End With

  End Sub
  ```